# multiple intermediate responses in java restful webservices

Tags: web-services

I am working on Java Restful webservices. As per my project requirement, when a client hit my web service I need to send him an immediate intermediate response of submission and need to proceed with the next steps in web services and return the actual result again to the client after completion. Could you please help me in solving the scenario.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I thought there is no immediate intermediate response we can send from server side. So this has to done from client side.First client has to check whether the specified web service url is reachable from their end or not. Then he has to call the web service for the actual result.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I solved it by using Multithreading concept.